# Markov chain: expected time of recurrent state

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expected-value

we have
$$
f_i := \mathbb P( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n = i\} | \{X_0 = i\})
\\
S_i = E[\sum_{n=1}^\infty1_{\{X_n=i\}} | X_0 = i]
$$

given
$$f_i = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P (N_i = n | X_0 = i), N_i = \min\{n>0:X_n=i\}$$

we want to show
$$
E[\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X_k=i\}}|N_i=n, X_0=i] = 1 + S_i
$$

Here is my attempt:
$$ \begin {align*}
 & E[\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{X_k=i\}}|N_i=n, X_0=i] \\ &=
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_k=i | N_i=n, X_0=i) \\ &=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_k = i|X_0 = i) + 1
\end {align*}
$$

We have $+1$ in the last step because when we sub the condition $N_i=n$ in, it is ensured that the chain transit state i twice. so the expected time is at least 1. I am wondering about the correctness of my answer.